# Don't need backdate publishing option in wordpress website

Tags: posts

I don't want backdate publishing of posts on my wordpress website.
Is there any way to stop authors from publishing posts in backdate?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.